# Comparing embedding differences between OpenAI (via httr2) and HuggingFace (via ‘text’)?

Tags: r, text, word-embedding, httr2

For two R libraries, I'm trying to understand the differencs between the embeddings for httr2 (OpenAI) and text (huggingface) libraries, respectively.   For example, is it possible to exchange/convert these two output embeddings?  Why are the embedding outputs so different?  And which one will be more valuable in performing cosine similarity comparisons against a corpus text?  More importantly, I'm struggling to make use of the OpenAI output, so curious about the OpenAI (httr2) value and purpose being in hex format.  The text library seems to be returning more detail versus the OpenAI (httr2) embedding.  How do I make use of the httr2 (OpenAI) returned hex embedding in comparison with the HuggingFace (via ‘text’)?

```
# Input code
library(httr2)
url_base <-"https://api.openai.com/v1/"
  
prompt <- "Please tell me a dad joke"
  
model_type<-"text-embedding-ada-002"
body <- list(input = prompt, 
model = model_type)
response<-request(url_base) |>
        req_url_path_append("embeddings") |>
        req_auth_bearer_token(token = api_key) |>
        req_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json") |> 
        req_user_agent("JustADude @justadude") |> 
        req_body_json(body)  |>
        req_perform()
```

```
#  Output  
response$body
   [1] 7b 0a 20 20 22 6f 62 6a 65 63 74 22 3a 20 22 6c 69 73 74 22 2c 0a 20 20 22 64 61 74 61 22 3a 20 5b 0a 20 20 20 20 7b 0a 20
  [42] 20 20 20 20 20 22 6f 62 6a 65 63 74 22 3a 20 22 65 6d 62 65 64 64 69 6e 67 22 2c 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 22 69 6e 64 65 78 22
```

Versus:

```
library(text)

texts <- c("Tell me a dad joke.")

# Transform the text data to BERT word embeddings
word_embeddings <- textEmbed(texts = texts,
                             model = "bert-base-uncased",
                             layers = -2,
                             aggregation_from_tokens_to_texts = "mean",
                             aggregation_from_tokens_to_word_types = "mean",
                             keep_token_embeddings = FALSE)

# See how word embeddings are structured
word_embeddings
```

```
Output: 
# A tibble: 8 × 770
  words     n    Dim1     Dim2    Dim3     Dim4    Dim5     Dim6     Dim7    Dim8    Dim9   Dim10   Dim11   Dim12   Dim13   Dim14
  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 .         1  0.0300 -0.523   -0.818   0.356   -0.374  -0.273   -3.26e-1  0.688   0.132  -0.358   0.590   0.0501 -0.578  -0.0596
2 [CLS]     1  0.137  -0.383   -0.259   0.216   -0.668  -0.511    7.39e-2  0.789   0.763  -0.155   0.361  -0.320  -0.196  -0.0264
3 [SEP]     1  0.0553  0.0223  -0.0227  0.0169  -0.0463 -0.0391  -3.77e-5 -0.0389  0.0405  0.0284 -0.0154 -0.0473  0.0269 -0.0656
4 a         1 -0.165   0.503   -0.254   0.0613   0.645  -0.630    7.91e-1  1.56    0.0416  0.267   0.604  -1.02   -0.782   0.693
```

Thank you for any details on the comparison on these two embedding types and styles and purposes.

Comment: Use something like `resp_body_string()` or `resp_body_json()` to parse the bytes in `response$body`. You are just seeing the raw bytes. You could also do `rawToChar(response$body)` but `httr2` is designed such that you generally don't use `$`, there are usually helper functions to extract parts of an object.

Comment: resp_body_string() seems to be very helpful for converting the returned the httr2 (OpenAI) embedding hex to decimal.   If possible, do you know if decimal  httr2 (OpenAI) return is equivalent to one of the text (huggingface) returns, e.g., CLS, SEP, or other?

Comment: I don't have my own api key so I can't run the code to see what it returns. And your output seems incomplete so I'm not sure what the contents are.

Comment: The title and text are somewhat confusing. ‘httr2’ isn’t a machine learning package, it doesn’t provide embeddings. What you’re comparing is OpenAI and HuggingFace (via ‘text’).

Comment: @KonradRudolph addressed the title.  Thanks for finding that improvement.

Comment: @MrFlick - After resp_body_string(), is there another command to just end up with the values in an array or list?   After resp_body_string() they seem to "{\n  \"object\": \"list\",\n  \"data\": [\n    {\n      \"object\": \"embedding\",\n      \"index\": 0,\n      \"embedding\": [\n        0.0028997671,\n        -0.009203743,\n        -0.014495741,\n

Comment: That looks like JSON data. resp_body_json() should parse that into a list.

Comment: Here's the mess I came up for it to work (probably a better way for those in the know): response_parsed <- response |> resp_body_json()
    
    array_parsed_embeddings<-as.array(unlist(response_parsed$data[1]))
    embedding_outout<-as.numeric(array_parsed_embeddings[3:length(array_parsed_embeddings)])